# BATCH — Store command output to variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to make a bat script that performs an action only if fewer than 2 occurrences of cmd.exe are running. I managed to find a solution that stores the occurrence count in a temporary file, but I find it very inelegant. So my question is how to do the same as below without a temporary file, but rather by storing the occurence count given by `@TASKLIST | FIND /I /C "%_process%"` in a variable. I saw that there may be a solution with a for loop, but I couldn’t get it to work and anyway I would really prefer a solution based on `SET` (if this is possible).

```
@SET _process=cmd.exe
@SET _temp_file=tempfiletodelete.txt
@TASKLIST | FIND /I /C "%_process%" > %_temp_file%
@SET /p _count=<%_temp_file%
@DEL /f %_temp_file%
@IF %_count% LSS 2 (
    @ECHO action 1
) ELSE (
    @ECHO action 2
)
```

**Edit:** This question is similar to [Save output from FIND command to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524239/save-output-from-find-command-to-variable), but I wasn’t able to apply the solution to my problem and I wanted to know if a solution without a for loop is possible.

Comment: `for /F %%a in ('@TASKLIST ^| FIND /I /C "%_process%"') do @SET "_count=%%a"`

Comment: To capture the output of a command you need to use [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) (you need to escape the pipe like `^|` then); there is no method based on `set`[`/P`], except using a temporary file...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save output from FIND command to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524239/save-output-from-find-command-to-variable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command **FOR** with option `/F` and the command or command line specified as *set* (string inside parentheses) additionally enclosed by `'` can be used for processing the output of a command or a command line with multiple commands on one line.

You can use this batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "_process=cmd.exe"
FOR /F %%I IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq %_process%" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I /C "%_process%"') DO SET "_count=%%I"
IF /I "%_process%" == "cmd.exe" SET /A _count-=1
IF %_count% LSS 2 (
    ECHO action 1
) ELSE (
    ECHO action 2
)
```

The command **FOR** runs in background without a visible console window `cmd.exe /C` with the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" | C:\Windows\System32\find.exe /I /C "cmd.exe"
```

**TASKLIST** option `/FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"` filters the output of **TASKLIST** already to processes with image name (= name of executable) `cmd.exe`. This makes further processing faster and avoids that a running process with file name `totalcmd.exe` is counted as `cmd.exe` as the command line in question does.

The output of **TASKLIST** written to handle **STDOUT** is redirected to handle **STDIN** of command **FIND** which processes the lines and counts the lines containing `cmd.exe` anywhere in line. **FIND** outputs finally the number of lines containing searched string to handle **STDOUT** of command process running in background.

The redirection operator `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with option `/F` captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of executed command process and processes each line. In this case just one line is captured by **FOR** containing just a number. Therefore no additional options are needed to assign the number assigned to loop variable `I` by **FOR** to environment variable `_count` using command **SET**.

The goal of this batch file is counting the number of `cmd.exe` processes already running. As the command line with **TASKLIST** and **FIND** is executed by **FOR** in background with using one more `cmd.exe` process, it is necessary to subtract the count by one to get the correct result using an arithmetic expression evaluated with `SET /A _count-=1`. This decrement by one is needed only for counting right the number of `cmd.exe` processes. It is not necessary for any other process.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `tasklist /?`

Comment: @Mofi Thank you for answer, it works perfectly and I accepted it. One thing that I don’t understand is why you use `%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe` instead of `TASKLIST` and `FIND`?

Comment: @nico Please take a look on [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) There are so many programmers and therefore also application installers which corrupt environment variable `PATH` that it is simply a matter of coding safety to write batch files being independent on environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` as much as possible by referencing executables in a batch file always with full qualified file name (= full path + file name + file extension).

Answer (score 5):

You would do it like this, using `TaskList` in a `For` loop:

```bat
@Set "_process=cmd.exe"
@For /F %%A In ('TaskList^|Find /C /I "%_process%"'
) Do @If %%A Lss 2 (Echo Action 1) Else Echo Action 2
@Pause
```

You can also perform a similar thing using `WMIC` too:

```bat
@Set "_process=cmd.exe"
@For /F %%A In ('WMIC Process Get Name^|Find /C "%_process%"'
) Do @If %%A Lss 2 (Echo Action 1) Else Echo Action 2
@Pause
```

These could be refined further to ensure processes containing the string as opposed to matching it aren't counted:

```bat
@Set "_process=cmd.exe"
@For /F %%A In ('TaskList /FI "ImageName Eq "%_Process%""^|Find /C "."'
) Do @If %%A Lss 2 (Echo Action 1) Else Echo Action 2
@Pause
```

```bat
@Set "_process=cmd.exe"
@For /F %%A In (
    'WMIC Process Where "Name='%_process%'" Get Name^|Find /C "."'
) Do @If %%A Lss 2 (Echo Action 1) Else Echo Action 2
@Pause
```

**Note**:
If you're really checking the `cmd.exe` process, be aware that an the command inside the `For` loop parentheses is spawned within a new `cmd.exe` instance, *(thereby increasing your count by `1`)*