# How to properly escape multiline output plus FOR plus %PROGRAMFILES(X86)% plus pipe, when stored in variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is working in cmd:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe" --list-content | FIND "Serial Number 12345-"
```

Output (correctly extracted from multiple lines):

> CmContainer with Serial Number 12345-67890 and version 1.19 (locked)

But I want to make it work in a .bat file and store the result to a variable (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526360/3890673)):

```
 for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`"C:\Program^ Files^ ^(x86)\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe" --list-content ^| FIND "Serial Number 12345-"`) do SET foobar=%%i
```

it throws:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

PS: in the final version I'd like to use system variables for the path, like `"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe"`, but while that does not make a difference in cmd, it throws *"'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."* when called from within a .bat... so I guess there are escaping issues?

Comment: Usually there is no need to escape anything except the `|` since the path is in between `""` that protect special characters; in this situation however the very first `"` and the very last one are considered as a pair and become removed prior to further processing; to prevent that put another but escaped pair around, so `... in ('^""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\..." ^| find "..."^"') ...`...

Comment: @aschipfl: `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. Doble checking by adding ^ only before first space: `'C:\Program Files' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: edited my first comment meanwhile...

Comment: Better, as the error msg is gone. However: The result still isn't the same as on command line, it's just `-` being stored in `foobar`... probably a different question though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your command line:

```cmd
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`"C:\Program^ Files^ ^(x86)\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe" --list-content ^| FIND "Serial Number 12345-"`) do SET foobar=%%i
```

the very first and last quotation mark of the expression behind `in` are considered as a pair that becomes removed; the remainder becomes then processed and is then recognised as wrong syntax.

To prevent that place another pair of quitation marks around, but escape them, like this:

```cmd
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`^""C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe" --list-content ^| FIND "Serial Number 12345-"^"`) do SET foobar=%%i
```

---

The reason for this odd behaviour is that `for /F` uses `cmd /S /c` to run the command line behind `in`, so this is what becomes executed, using your code (without any escaping):

```cmd
cmd /S /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe" --list-content | FIND "Serial Number 12345-"
```

`cmd /S` strips the first and last `"` and leaves behind the following line, which is invalid syntax:

```cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe" --list-content | FIND "Serial Number 12345-
```

Now to avoid such a strange remainder, give to `cmd` some explicit quotation marks to remove:

```cmd
cmd /S /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe" --list-content | FIND "Serial Number 12345-""
```

The escaping I suggested is intended for the command path (including `)`) to appear in between a pair of quotation marks in order not to have to care about any further escaping (like `^)`):

```cmd
cmd /S /c ^""C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe" --list-content | FIND "Serial Number 12345-"^"
```

---

You do not need the `usebackq` option, but you may need `delims=` to not split the received string at white-spaces, like this:

```cmd
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\CodeMeter\Runtime\bin\cmu32.exe" --list-content ^| FIND "Serial Number 12345-"^"') do SET "foobar=%%i"
```

Comment: Do need `usebackq`, get `The system cannot find the file `""C:\Program.` (note the double quote), but delims did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Well, `usebackq` does not change handling of double-quotes here, it just lets you use ` instead of `'`...